# Are there different idioms for these two different kinds of scratches?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

I don't even know if "scratch" applies to both cases:

1. I slice a (slightly) harder object on a (slightly) softer surface. It leaves an inwards scratch. The harder object is not damaged at all, but some material from the softer one is lost or merely displaced. Ex: a putty knife on putty, or a metal object on a potato, etc.
2. I slice a softer object on a harder surface. It leaves a mark on the harder object, and the softer one "grinds" thus getting slightly damaged. Ex: Chalk on a chalkboard, a metal knife on a porcelain dish.

So, what should word these phrases?

- The putty knife made a __________ on the clay block.
- The knife made a __________ on the porcelain dish.

Answer (score 2):

In your question, what is on top of the underlying surface doesn't matter since your question is about how the underlying surface is affected.

If a surface is soft, it can either be cut through or an indent or mark might be left on it

> The putty knife made a **indent** on the clay block.

[image: here]

The knife left **marks** on the cutting board.

[image: here]
If the underlying surface is very hard, where the substrate can not be affected, only the surface can be **scratched**

> The knife made made a **scratch** on the porcelain dish.
>   The knife left **marks** on the porcelain dish.

[image: here]
[image: here]